# Electron не поддерживает defer в теге <script>?

Tags: javascript, electron

Собственно, вопрос в заголовке.
 
Окно не отрисовывается до тех пор, пока скрипт не будет выполнен. Так задумано?

Answer (score 1):

`defer` откладывает запуск скрипта до момента загрузки основной части страницы - но не влияет на основное свойство скриптов (однопоточность). Можно сказать - да, так и задумано.

Поэтому тяжелые вычисления нужно выносить хотя бы в главный процесс, а лучше в Web Worker или в дополнительный процесс.

Comment: Почитал про web worker'ы. Что-то не получается. Создаю worker: <script>var worker = new Worker("script2.js");</script>. В script2.js простой alert(). Скрипт просто не вызывается. Что я делаю неправильно?

Comment: @Artik воркер - это фоновой процесс, в нем не может быть алертов

Comment: Тогда понятно. А как тогда можно реализовать простейшую задачу: вывод содержимого с разметкой в главное окно Electron'а с последующим выводом alert'а? В браузерах и nw.js это решается простым атрибутом defer.
*Пардон за глупые, наверное, вопросы. Я только начинаю изучать javascript.